Dataflow Returns Empty
I have a DataFlow named "DigitalShopify" and I want to import one of its dataset into Power Query
When I check the DataFlow, everything works just fine. But when I try to import it into Power Query, it returns me nothing
My DataFlow Screenshot
I also check the error log, but it only gives me IDs
error with Request ID: a7cac5a7-4a50-1236-e3a8-f8d432b56085 Activity ID: 272ae5f9-ab7f-42ed-9e15-6e514de8cec1

Could anyone give me any clue about this?
I want to import my dataset from dataflow into Power Query

It's likely you don't enough permission to access the dataflow. Check the permission given in Power BI Desktop. Also, try to refresh the dataflow to make sure it contains the latest data.
